# Broken links in the unsubscribe page

Tags: bug

Each of the 'Manage' links (Community Digests, Questions Subscriptions, Saved Job Search Alerts) fail with 'Invalid Request' and a 403 in the console. The same behavior occurs when clicking any of the navigation links under 'Email Settings'. I reached this page from the newsletter unsubscribe link while logged in. Interestingly, if I click the same link from a private tab, I just get "You are now unsubscribed from this email".

This seems to only affect the unsubscribe page (https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/unsubscribe/...), not the standard email settings equivalent (https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/...).