# Unsubscribe link broken again

Tags: bug

Possibly related (but still unanswered) [Broken links in the unsubscribe page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411722/broken-links-in-the-unsubscribe-page).

I got an email this morning: "Notice: Discontinuing Stack Overflow Developer Story"

I clicked "Unsubscribe from emails like this" which takes me to https://stackoverflow.email/subscriptions/unsubscribe-bucket/

This results in a 404.

[image]